# Cast object to Class stored in variable

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible to store a class type in a variable and later use that variable to cast an object to that class type?

I seem to be able to store the class type in a variable in the enum, but have been unable to us this variable to cast a new object to this type.

I have an enum of subclassed types

```
enum FruitType: Int {

    case orange, apple, lemon, lime

    var className: Fruit.Type {
        switch self {
            case.orange:
                return Orange.self
            case.apple:
                return Apple.self
            case.lemon:
                return Lemon.self
            case.lime:
                return Lime.self
        }
    }
}
```

I have subclasses for these game objects (Orange, Apple, Lemon & Lime) and they all inherit from "Fruit"

Later on I am trying to use that variable to cast an object to that type but it reports an error

> error "Use of undeclared type 'fruitType'

```
func createFruit(fruitType: FruitType, name: String) {
    if let orange = self.childNode(withName: name) as? fruitType.className {
        self.orange = orange
    }
    etc...
}
```

I've also tried `fruitType.className(self.childNode(withName: name))` with the same results

I've looked into Generics but couldn't find anything that fit this situation.

> EDIT to show actual example

The above question was simplified to make the question easier to state. The true nature of how I am handling this is that I am loading a SKS scene file as a SKReferenceNode based on fruitType and I need to cast that SKReferenceNode accordingly

```
func loadFruit(fruitType: FruitType) {

    var fruit: Fruit!
    if let fruitFile = SKReferenceNode(filename: fruitType.fileName) {

        if let fruitNode = fruitFile.childNode(withName: fruitType.name) as? fruitType.className {
             fruitNode.setup()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do an as? cast to a type that isn't known until runtime.  You should be casting to whatever type `self.orange` is.

Comment: @dan what you say makes sense, this is not my real code though. I've dumbed down the example to not complicate the question. What I really am doing is loading a SKS scene file as a SKReferenceNode based on fruitType and I need to cast that SKReferenceNode accordingly

Comment: But why do you need to cast it to anything other than the common superclass type?  Even if it worked to cast like you are in your code, you wouldn't be able to access any properties on the object after you casted because the compiler would still have no idea what type it is.

Comment: casting as the parent type doesn't call the subclass initializers. so it no longer thinks of them as "orange" just Fruit

Comment: Casting doesn't call any initializer.  If your object is getting initialized incorrectly then it's because of a problem in your `childNode(withName:)` method.

Comment: I didn't mean initialize the object as in calling an initializer (poor choice of words) I meant associate those subclassed properties with that object

Comment: Right, that was the point of my second comment.  `fruitType.className` is a runtime value.  The compiler needs to know the type at compile time to let you access any properties on the object.

Comment: @RonMyschuk An instance of a given subclass will still have all of its properties that are declared in the subclass, irrespective of the static type of the instance. Casting merely changes the *static* type of an instance, the runtime type remains fixed. The point that dan is making is that you cannot change the static type of an instance to a type that isn't known until runtime.

Comment: @dan I understand, so basically if I can't have that knowledge at compile time, the answer to my question, is no this cannot be done...correct?

Comment: I could have sworn this question was asked before, but what you are asking for is just dangerous.  I will provide a better answer for you,  I think what you need to do is work with `protocols` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Why does `enum FruitType` need to exist?  If you've got `class Fruit`, then you get `Fruit.Type` automatically.  Why make a custom copy of an existing (meta)type, and all the grief from this impedance mismatch?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you are correct protocols would help much of this. however that just fixes some of the funcs that I would need to access AFAIK. What I am working on is a Dialog manager that manages any popups/custom sprite alerts/menus that I want to display in the game (iap's, pause menu, gameover). While they all inherit from class of Dialog, many of them has subtle diffs, such as on a level up dialog, I need to expose a property of "level" to display corresponding info that Pause dialog doesn't have. I was looking for a cleaner way to output a dialog vs. the 17 item switch statement I have.

Comment: That is what protocols are for, and protocols can inherit other protocols, so you have flexibility

Comment: What is dangerous in your case, is what if you have Orange, and you cast it to Potato by accident, your code is going to fail, and you will have no idea why

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Wouldn't "as? variable.className" (assuming I could get that to work) prevent it from getting missclassed? In my sks file I do declare the node as a specific class type "Potato". wouldn't the "if as?" prevent potato from ever being told it was an Orange?

Comment: your `as` is going to make it return nil, which means you do not create a new fruit.  This is your code failing to do what it is suppose to do.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks. sometimes ideas are much easier in my head than the actual implementations. I will look into inheriting protocols

Comment: I tell people this all the time, when you seem to have an issue with how logic works on a machine,  then just write down the logic you want on a piece of paper in english (or your native language.)  You will find it a lot easier to translate from english to swift, than it is to think about the logic only swift

Answer (score -2):

May be this will help you:

Factory Method:
The factory pattern is used to replace class constructors, abstracting the process of object generation so that the type of the object instantiated can be determined at run-time.

https://github.com/ochococo/Design-Patterns-In-Swift#-factory-method

Comment: People please comment when you do a downvote, this will help Sergey Di and others learn from their mistakes.  Sergey Di, unfortunately the factory method does not really help answer the problem Ron Myschuk is having.  Now I will agree it does make sense to create a factory, the problem is Ron Myschuk is looking for a specific instance, rather than an abstract type.  Perhaps if you better explain how the factory method helps Ron, people will be more inclined to upvote you.